# Python trouble with JSON objects schema to parse iTunes id lookup

Tags: python, json, python-3.5

I am trying to parse the information about applications form the itunes lookup tool for example https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=880047117.

Right now I am trying to open up a connection using requests, JSON and a JSON objects schema. However the schema keeps failing with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_and_query.py", line 33, in <module>
    details = get_app_details(880047117)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jsonobjects/schema.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return self.parse(func(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jsonobjects/fields.py", line 169, in parse
    return self.run_validation(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jsonobjects/fields.py", line 136, in run_validation
    is_empty, value = self.validate_empty_values(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jsonobjects/fields.py", line 105, in validate_empty_values
    self.fail('required')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jsonobjects/fields.py", line 165, in fail
    raise ValidationError(msg.format(**kwargs), self.field_name)
jsonobjects.exceptions.ValidationError: ['This field is required.']
```

The schema is declared as it's own class object and instantiated but it continually fails. I have the ID's of apps that I would like to look up the JSON information on. If there is an easier way that I am missing please let me know, I don't have access to the iTunes API.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5                                                      

import json                                                                     
import requests                                                                 
import jsonobjects as jo                                                        
from jsonschema import Draft4Validator                                          


class iTunesAppSchema(jo.Schema):                                               
    id = jo.IntegerField('trackId')                                             
    url = jo.Field('trackViewUrl')                                              
    name = jo.StringField('trackName')                                           
    rating = jo.FloatField('averageUserRating')                                    
    reviews = jo.IntegerField('userRatingCountForCurrentVersion')                  
    version = jo.StringField('version')                                            
    bundle_id = jo.StringField('bundleId')                                         
    publisher_id = jo.IntegerField('artistId')                                     
    publisher_url = jo.Field('artistViewUrl')                                      
    publisher_name = jo.StringField('artistName')                                  
    categories = jo.ListField('genres', child=jo.StringField())                    



parser = iTunesAppSchema('results[0]')                                             

@parser.as_decorator                                                               
def get_app_details(app_id):                                                       
    url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id={}'                                  
    return requests.get(url.format(app_id)).json()                                 

# https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=880047117                                     
details = get_app_details(880047117)                                               
print(details)
```

Comment: Why are you using jsonobject?  <opinion> That type of parsing is only necessary when offering a service, not when using it. </opinion>

Comment: I am just trying to break the information out into an object that I can manipulate. Is there an easier way?

Comment: What do you mean with 'manipulate'? import json; json.loads(results[0]) gives you a native Python object that can be used freely.